# How do i get the ID of the current form in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

i'm using admin.py in django and i want to know how can i get my current id from the form just for customize the page. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: means do you want to add id to your model in admin panel?

Comment: Nope, i want it to customize some fields